# How to typedef a class constructor inside the class definition

Tags: c++

The title might be unclear but the code is simple and should explain itself. I would like to typedef a constructor to my class inside the class and then set the address of said constructor elsewhere.

```
class Dog {
public:
    typedef Dog* (__thiscall* Constructor_T)(Dog* thisptr);
    static Constructor_T Constructor;

    Dog() {
        Constructor(this);
    }
};

void SetDogConstructor() {
    Dog::Constructor = (Dog::Constructor_T)0x1234;
}
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error   2   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class Dog * (__thiscall* Dog::Constructor)(class Dog *)" (?Constructor@Dog@@2P6EPAV1@PAV1@@ZA)
```

Comment: You cannot "typedef a constructor". A constructor is a function. A type is a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static member needs a definition outside the class.  In your case, you would put

```
Dog::Constructor_T Dog::Constructor = nullptr;
```

in Dog.cpp.